# Can we control speed of value updating in a WPF user control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I am using a custom wpf control, and value of this control will change at every 20 millisecond based on a channel value update from a database. But i want to control the speed value update in this user control so that it can easily understandable to user (which means ~500ms), do we have any solution other than threading in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Create a buffer between the control and the fast changing data source.

You could create a buffer by making a class with a property that will keep track of when the last update to its property was made and only when it is more than 500 ms ago will update the property.

```
private int _stockRate;
private long _lastUpdate = 0;

public int StockRate
{
    get { return _stockRate; }
    set 
    {
         long now = getTimeInMilliseconds(); // Stopwatch or other timer
         if(now - _lastUpdate > 500ms)
         {
             _stockRate = value;
             _lastUpdate = now;
             OnPropertyChanged("StockRate");
         }
    }
}
```